# Como redirecionar de não-www para www?

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Quero que os visitantes do meu site acessem sempre com `www`.

Quero de alguma forma redirecionar caso o usuário tente entrar sem `www` ou subdominio. Se tentarem acessar `exemplo.com` quero redirecionar para `www.exemplo.com`.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Interessante! 
Apenas para complementar existe um site que promove a remoção do www.

Faça um teste:
http://no-www.org/verify.php?u=SEUDOMINIO.COM&retest=1 

Domínios de Classe A (Aceitam tanto com WWW quanto sem WWW).
Domínios de Classe B (Redirecionam o WWW para sem WWW).
Domínios de Classe C (Rejeitam o WWW e apenas aceitam sem - não recomendado)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar o [IIS URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite). Para usar em um servidor basta baixar e instalar. Shared hosts normalmente incluem este modulo.

Com este modulo instalado basta configurar regras.

Para redirecionar permanentemente (Redirect 301) de `não-www` para `www`, você pode incluir esta regra, configurando o domínio apropriadamente:

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
   <rule name="Canonical" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^([a-z]+[.]com)$" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{C:0}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
</rewrite>
```

Se por algum motivo você não puder utilizar o URL Rewrite, você pode fazer por código. No `Global.asax.cs` adicione

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs ev)
{
    if (!Request.Url.Host.Equals("example.com", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("Location", 
            String.Format("{0}://www.{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Host, Request.Url.PathAndQuery)
            );
        Response.StatusCode = 301;
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Há vantagens em utilizar o `www`. Você pode ter subdominios *cookieless*, por exemplo `static.exemplo.com`. E neste domínio você pode exibir imagens que vão ser baixadas sem a necessidade de baixar cookies. Para [mais informações veja esta explicação](http://www.ravelrumba.com/blog/static-cookieless-domain/). [Pense bem sobre isso](https://twitter.com/codinghorror/statuses/1637428313).

---

Se você quer redirecionar de `www` para `não-www` (*cokieless* não é importante para você), você pode configurar o IIS Rewrite com:

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Canonical" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www[.](.+)" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:1}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

E caso não possa utilizar este modulo e precise fazer por código, adicione ao `Global.asax.cs`

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs ev)
{
    if (Request.Url.Host.StartsWith("www", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("Location", 
            String.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", Request.Url.Scheme, Request.Url.Host.Substring(4), Request.Url.PathAndQuery)
            );
        Response.StatusCode = 301;
        Response.End();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Uma forma de promover isso é tirar vantagem dos módulos do ASP.Net. Você pode criar um módulo que entrará na [pipeline de execução do ASP.Net](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252.aspx) e interceptar o "www". Para isso basta criar uma classe que herda a interface `IHttpModule`, e adicionar uma linha nova no seu Web.Config.

Dessa forma você mantém seu Global.asax limpo, e não utiliza o Web.Config para instruír o navegador a fazer redirects.

#### Classe para criar o módulo de redirect

```
public class RemoveWWW : IHttpModule
{
    public void Dispose(){}

    // Expressão Regular para identificar o www
    private static Regex regex = new Regex("(http|https)://www\\.", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Compiled);

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        // Intercepta o Begin Request
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(BeginRequestHandler);
    }
    void BeginRequestHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication application = sender as HttpApplication;
        Uri url = application.Context.Request.Url;
        bool contemWWW = regex.IsMatch(url.ToString());

        if (contemWWW)
        {
            // Esse replace é importante para manter o protocolo HTTP ou HTTPS
            string novaUrl = regex.Replace(url.ToString(), String.Format("{0}://", url.Scheme));

            // Redirect 302 ou 301 não fazem diferença para o Google, pois ele não faz distinção entre www.example.com e example.com
            application.Context.Response.Redirect(novaUrl);
        }
    }
}
```

Depois a parte mais simples, adicionar o módulo no Web.Config

```
<system.web>
  <httpModules>
    <add name="RemoveWWW" type="NAMESPACE_DO_PROJETO.RemoveWWW, NomeDoAssembly"/>
  <httpModules>
<system.web>
```

Você pode compilar em uma DLL separada e referenciar no seu projeto, reutilizando a mesma solução em outros projetos, apenas adicionando o módulo.

O principal motivo de evitar usar o Web.Config para para isso é manutenção e suporte. Incluindo regras de redirect no Web.Config abre um leque para os clientes editarem erroneamente, aumentando custo de suporte técnico. E caso em determinado cenário deseja desativar o módulo é simples como remover a linha do Web.Config, coisa que exigiria um trabalho extra no Global.asax

Um ponto positivo para os módulos é a reusabilidade de código. [Há um artigo que dá algumas idéias a mais de como usar os Http Modules para outras coisas](http://codebetter.com/karlseguin/2006/06/12/global-asax-use-httpmodules-instead/).

Comment: Isso não responde a pergunta, visto que está fazendo o contrário: Removendo o www da url. O @AP queria adicionar o www caso o usuário não tivesse o mesmo.