# Remover "www" do domínio fazendo redirecionamento 301

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Como eu faço redirecionamento de um `www.dominio.com.br` para `dominio.com.br` (sem www)?

Estou usando *asp.net mvc*.

Comment: Isso normalmente é na configuração de hospedagem do site

Comment: Não tenho certeza, mas os votos negativos me parecem que foram devidos a maneira que a pergunta foi escrita, eu editei pra ficar mais clara. +1 pra pergunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Nota: No inicio achei que era uma duplicata de [Como redirecionar de não-www para www?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/132/3635) mas ao ler notei que a pergunta aqui é remover o "www" e não adicionar, na outra pergunta não vi exemplos de remover o "www" por isto estou respondendo aqui.

Encontrei duas respostas no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3197319/1518921):

- Editando o *web.config* (o `redirectType="Permanent"` indica redirecionamento permanente que é o 301):

  ```
  <system.webServer>
      <rewrite>
          <rules>
              <rule name="Remove WWW prefix" >
                  <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
                  <conditions>
                      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.domain\.com" />
                  </conditions>
                  <action type="Redirect" url="http://domain.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
              </rule>
          </rules>
      </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
  ```

  Se preferir adicionar www, mude para:

  ```
              <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^domain\.com" /> 
          </conditions> 
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" /> 
      </rule>
  ```
- Usando a linguagem de programação, no caso um exemplo com C#:

  ```
  protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     if (Request.Url.Host.StartsWith ("www") && !Request.Url.IsLoopback)
     {
        UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(Request.Url);
        builder.Host = Request.Url.Host.Replace("www.","");
        Response.StatusCode = 301;
        Response.AddHeader("Location", builder.ToString());
        Response.End();
     }
  }
  ```

  Se preferir adicionar www, mude para:

  ```
  UriBuilder builder = new UriBuilder(Request.Url);
  builder.Host = "www." + Request.Url.Host;
  ```

Comment: Obrigado, @Guilherme Nascimento funcionou.