# Como adiconar "www." em um site com web.config?

Tags: asp, web.config

Não tenho muito conhecimento em expressões regulares e estou tentando identificar se ao acessar o site o usuário digitou www antes do nome do site.

Caso ele não tenha digitado, eu tenho que adicionar. Mas estou com um pouco de dificuldades de fazer isso no web config do asp. Tentei algo assim:

```
<rule name="teste">
  <match url="^([^w]\w*)">;
  <action type="Rewrite" url="www.{R:1}">
</rule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seguindo a lógica desta outra resposta que fiz [Remover “www” do domínio fazendo redirecionamento 301](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/106521/3635), a diferença é que tem que "trocar" o `action type="Redirect"` pelo `add input`:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Adiciona prefixo WWW">
                <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^MEUDOMINIO\.com" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.MEUDOMINIO.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Acabei conseguindo fazer também de uma forma parecida. Segue o exemplo para quem precisar:

```
<rule name="Add WWW" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="^(.*)$" />
  <conditions>
     <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^(?!www\.)(.*)$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{C:0}{PATH_INFO}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```